# bash/zsh prompt displaying Git repository data right-aligned

Tags: git, bash, zsh, prompt

I saw this in a [Github video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLR1RNqJ1Mw) and would like the same right-aligned prompt in my shell.

How can I accomplish it?

or even better

Which prompt is used here?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this by setting the `RPROMPT` zsh variable. Example: to display the current time,

```
RPROMPT='$(date +%T)'
```

Make sure the `promptsubst` option is set by looking at the output of `setopt`. If it isn't, use `setopt promptsubst` in your `.zshrc` or equivalent.

In your case, use the appropriate `git` command telling you the branch.

For the gory details, read `man zshmisc`, especially the section `EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES`.